# ¿Cómo puedo agregar una descripción o doble texto a un botón o switch en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-button

Sinceramente no tengo idea de como agregar eso. He intento continuar el texto con doble linea, pero estéticamente no se me hace atractivo. Al ser posible añadir una descripción me gustaria optar por utilizarla, pero no sé como añadirla.

Esto es lo que tengo:

[image: Diseño de mi switch]

Y a la descripción que **me refiero es al texto que suele aparecer con un color gris**:

[image: Ejemplo]

Este es el código del switch que he diseñado:

```html
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:id="@+id/idNumberBar"
                style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:onClick="activateNumberBar"
                android:text="@string/number_bar"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
      android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Body1"
                android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize">
</androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat>
```

Comment: Desconozco si realmente existe una función específica para eso pero en mi caso te lo mostraré como lo haría yo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero de todo es que utilizo el `ConstraintLayout` para esto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_margin="24dp">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Luego de eso, para este caso que es solo visualización agrego tres `TextView` y un `SwitchMaterial`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvEjemplo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ejemplo"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPrimerTexto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/primerTexto"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvEjemplo"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTextoOculto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:text="@string/textoOculto"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvPrimerTexto"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

<com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
    android:id="@+id/ejemploSwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/tvPrimerTexto"/>
```

Como para ponerte un poco en contexto, el primer `TextView` es solo un mero título. El segundo es el `TextView` que se muestra en la misma línea del `SwitchMaterial` y el tercer `TextView` es el que se "ocultaría/mostraría" por defecto le pondremos la propiedad `visibility` en `invisible`. Para que esto sea funcional, lo primero es ir a la `MainActivity` y declararlos:

```
SwitchMaterial ejemploSwitch;
TextView tvTextoOculto;
```

Luego, dentro del `onCreate` les paso el id propio de cada elemento que voy a utilizar:

```
    ejemploSwitch = findViewById(R.id.ejemploSwitch);
    tvTextoOculto = findViewById(R.id.tvTextoOculto);
```

Ahora, para **mostrar/ocultar** el texto debemos usar el evento `OnCheckedChanged`:

```
    ejemploSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener((compoundButton, b) -> {
        
    });
```

Dentro del evento, lo único que debemos hacer es un if para consultar el estado del `SwitchMaterial`:

```
        if(b){
            tvTextoOculto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            tvTextoOculto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

Para finalizar dejo todo el `Layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_margin="24dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEjemplo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ejemplo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPrimerTexto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/primerTexto"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvEjemplo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTextoOculto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="@string/textoOculto"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvPrimerTexto"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
        android:id="@+id/ejemploSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/tvPrimerTexto"/>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Dejo todo el MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SwitchMaterial ejemploSwitch;
    TextView tvTextoOculto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ejemploSwitch = findViewById(R.id.ejemploSwitch);
        tvTextoOculto = findViewById(R.id.tvTextoOculto);
        ejemploSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener((compoundButton, b) -> {
            if(b){
                tvTextoOculto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                tvTextoOculto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Y dejo capturas de cómo se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]